# Get undefined when stripe return result

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

Hello guy I am doing payment with stripe, I am already success payment (checked on dashboard.striped.com) but i can't get the result return. Below is my code
[image]
Node

```
app.post('/payment', async (req, res) => {
  const { token,
    totalPrice } = req.body
  const idempontencyKey = uuidv4()
  return stripe.customers.create({
    email:token.email,
    source:token.id
  }).then(customer => {
    stripe.charges.create({
      amount: Math.ceil(totalPrice),
      currency: 'usd',
      customer:customer.id,
    },{idempotencyKey: idempontencyKey})
  }).then(result => {
    res.status(200).json(result) // result in here is undefined
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

Here is my checkout component

```
<StripeCheckout stripeKey='pk_test_51KU0KNHzr2aPULLHERi1fWVBHp2Oxy1BTeBG0gfJ6O9DeRwuiGN1csKbpJMMPLvZjHTv5bo2qKguE8RQZnpCekjD00KDxRcNhm' token={makePayment} name='Buy product' amount={order.totalPrice} >
   <ButtonComponent>Pay ${order.totalPrice}</ButtonComponent>
</StripeCheckout>
```

And this is makePayment

```
const makePayment = async (token) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    const data = await axios.post('/payment', {
      token,
      totalPrice: order.totalPrice
    }, config)
    console.log('data',data.data) // this return empty string
  }
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you!!!

Comment: You forgot to return a value in the `.then(customer => { … }` block.

Answer (score 1):

The part

```
}).then(customer => {
  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: Math.ceil(totalPrice),
    currency: 'usd',
    customer:customer.id,
  },{idempotencyKey: idempontencyKey})
})
```

does not return anything, so the next `.then` will receive `undefined`.

Change it to

```
}).then(customer => {
  return stripe.charges.create({
    amount: Math.ceil(totalPrice),
    currency: 'usd',
    customer:customer.id,
  },{idempotencyKey: idempontencyKey})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In this then, you just call create charges function but return nothing. So that in the next then, it receive nothing.

```
}).then(customer => {
  return stripe.charges.create({
    amount: Math.ceil(totalPrice),
    currency: 'usd',
    customer:customer.id,
  },{idempotencyKey: idempontencyKey})
})
```